# 3rd party active directory component with built-in functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I still havent' figured out active directory, so I was hoping you guys could recommend some 3rd party components that would have all the built in methods done for me :)

I usually build my own users table with permissions/role tables, but want to add active directory as an option so you can tap into users already setup on windows servers.

.NET component

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify a language. Here's one for .NET:

http://www.dotnetactivedirectory.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 3.5, you can use the [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace to make AD operations a whole lot easier.

Comment: interesting, a new user friendly API is it?

Comment: @Blankman: yes - saw it in MSDN magazine early this year (or late last year). Being allergic to LDAP, it really caught my eye.